# Como chamar uma função 'this' quando minha função não reconhece?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Na pergunta ficou difícil de explicar, mas meu problema é o sequinte, adicionei no meu componente  o componente de teclado. Porém na função `_keyboardDidHide` estou chamando outra função que está no props. Porém gera um erro falando que `this.props.closeModal()` é indefinido, entre outras palavras é como se não estivesse declarada, mas tenho certeza que essa função funciona, pois minha modal no `onRequestClose` chama ela normalmente e funciona.

É como se qualquer coisa que eu coloque dentro da função `_keyboardDidHide` não compartilhasse as mesmas variaves do escopo do meu component. Existe alguma solução quanto a isso?

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this._keyboardDidShow,
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this._keyboardDidHide,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow() {
    alert('Keyboard Shown');
  }

  _keyboardDidHide() {
    this.props.closeModal();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
          transparent={true}
          visible={this.props.modalVisible}
          style={styles.container}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.props.closeModal();
          }}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}/>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Vinicius, já tentou fazer o bind da _keyboardDidHide com o this da sua class? Tipo this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this). Quando utilize react tive que fazer isso diversas vezes...

Comment: O `this` representa elemento ou evento que está ocorrendo dentro do escopo atual, você pode usar o console.log() para ver qual o this que está vindo no momento.

Comment: Entendi, tive que fazer isso no listener: `() => this._keyboardDidHide()`.